# How do i remove the black box border from my magento website?

Tags: css, magento, border

Please help me, i can't seem to figure out a way to remove the black border box surrounding all my product images and containers.

My website is [tucsons.ng](https://tucsons.ng)

here is a sample of what i really want gone

my site right now = https://postimg.cc/xXCq5SBg

my desired result = https://postimg.cc/V0gL97R3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is added by this CSS code:

```
.products-grid .product-item-info .product-item-photo {
    ...
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    ...
}
```

If you remove that line from css, the border will be gone.

I can't tell the exact location of the file because of static content deploy.
But seems like the name of the file is product-1.css.

Comment: Thanks @Gerard de visser

found the product-1.css file under /html/app/design/frontend/Sm/smartech/web/css

edited it out and i have been solved